# How to assign multiple different interface names on the same NIC card (hardware MAC address)

Tags: linux, networking, ip, network-interface, mac-address

I am using an Ubuntu Linux system. For my task I have to run some modules by executing the respective scripts. All the modules must run at the same time in the background but all have different interface names, IPv4 & IPv6 addresses configuration. So, basically I have to run different modules simultaneously having different IP configuration.

Here I am specifying all the NIC card interfaces' addresses and their corresponding names in a persistent net rules file. Suppose I have one NIC card MAC address and want to have two different interface names associated with the same MAC address. I know we can assign multiple virtual IP addresses to a particular interface by making alias of it.
But how can we assign different interface names to a particular hardware MAC address?

### For example:

Persistent-net-generator.rules rules file.
We can modify it, as long as you keep each rule on a single line, and change only the value of the NAME= key.

```
net device ()
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:04:9f:02:81:97", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

net device ()
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:04:9f:02:81:96", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"

net device ()
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:04:9f:02:81:95", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth2"
```

How can I get two interface names associated with the MAC address "00:04:9f:02:81:97"?

Comment: Did you mean ethernet virtual interface like eth0,eth0:1,eth0:2,etc ?  You can create many virtual interface on eth0 with one MAC address.

Comment: You can just change it's MAC address using `ifconfig NIC hw ether 00:04:9f:02:81:97`. replace NIC with the desired interface name. But I don't know if this solves your problem.

Comment: @supriady, But there is an issue. You should attention to how many same roles, device can play.
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328212/single-wifi-card-connect-to-multiple-access-points-simultaneously

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the new iproute2 [network interface alternative name](https://lwn.net/Articles/794289/) feature (`ip link altname`). Note that the command syntax seems to have changed since that article. For example:

```
ip link property add dev eth0 altname someothername
```

Note that this is very new, you will need a recent version of `iproute2` for it to work (`v5.4.0` which came out on 2019-11-25, if I'm reading the git log right).