# Theoretical: TAP interface w/ WIFI parent interface

Tags: wifi, networkmanager, dhcp, bridge, tap

I'm trying to create multiple Linux TAP interfaces and allow them to send/receive packets over a single WIFI adapter. For all intents and purposes I'd like the TAP interfaces to act as full fledged network adapters. They should be able to request their own DHCP addresses and interact on the local network as any other network adapter might.

I've managed to get this working with an Ethernet adapter but I've heard WiFi is a different beast. I can't remember the exact reasoning but it had something to do with "1 IP address per radio broadcast address".

Is it possible, using TAP interfaces, to essentially do bridged networking over a WiFi connection? Could I do any of the configuration with networkmanager? Can someone link an article or two? I'm having a tough time finding anything on this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This Network Engineering SE link [Four layer-2 addresses in 802.11 frame header](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25100/four-layer-2-addresses-in-802-11-frame-header/25102#25102) explains quite well the difference between Ethernet and Wifi.

Wifi requires additional MAC addresses for communication: in addition to the Sender Address (SA) and Destination Address (DA) which are the same as Ethernet's source and destination MACs, Wifi needs Transmitter Address (TA) and Receiver Address (RA) to work: this makes a total of 4 MACs addresses. Since the common case is that when the client (STA) sends, TA = SA and when the Access Point (AP) sends to the STA, DA = RA, usually only 3 addresses are needed, and that's how AP are configured: to use only 3 addresses out of the 4 possible.

A client in bridge mode means that above TA != SA or DA != RA and all 4 addresses are needed, while the AP is configured for 3 only. That's why in common configurations it's not possible to bridge Wifi. 4 addresses mode must be enabled on both the AP and the STA for client bridging to work. This is usually called [Wireless distribution system (WDS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_distribution_system), but there are probably multiple incompatible implementations. AP and all STA must use a compatible implementation.

So:

- if the system bridging is the AP, then you can bridge wifi without issue: that's what are doing all APs, using the default 3 addresses mode.
- if the system trying to bridge is a simple client (STA), it won't work. Recent drivers will even prevent setting the wireless interface as bridge port with this kind of error:

  ```
  # ip link set wlan0 master bridge0
  Error: Device does not allow enslaving to a bridge.
  ```
- if you can configure **both** the AP and the STA into a compatible WDS, for example if all are running Linux with drivers compatible with mac80211, this can be enabled on the STA with:

  ```
  # iw dev wlan0 set 4addr on
  ```

Then it can be enslaved:

```
    # ip link set wlan0 master bridge0
    # ip link show wlan0
    3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master bridge0 state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    [...]
```

Some documentation about 4 addresses mode with the iw command can be found on the linux wireless wiki: [Using 4-address for AP and client mode](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation/iw#using_4-address_for_ap_and_client_mode)

Configuring the AP is out of scope here. When using [hostapd](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/hostapd/hostapd.conf), there's a specific setting to enable:

> ```
> # WDS (4-address frame) mode with per-station virtual interfaces
> # (only supported with driver=nl80211)
> # This mode allows associated stations to use 4-address frames to allow layer 2
> # bridging to be used.
> #wds_sta=1
> ```

---

There's still a workaround allowing to use multiple containers or VMs simultaneously with separate IPs over a single Wifi default mode (3-addresses mode) connection, but using only *one* MAC address (the one used as STA): it's thus **usually not compatible with DHCP** which by default relies on the MAC address (unless the DHCP server is accepting the [*dhcp-client-identifier* option](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/isc-dhcp-common/dhcp-options.5.en.html#STANDARD_DHCPV4_OPTIONS)). It's called [IPVLAN](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ipvlan.txt) (usually for containers) and its TAP counterpart (usually for VMs) is called [IPVTAP](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/IPVTAP.html). When used in L2 mode it gives what looks like a standard ethernet interface.

For a (simple [ip netns](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/ip-netns.8) network) container this could be used like this after having already established a Wifi connection in the IP LAN 192.0.2.0/24 with gateway 192.0.2.1, on the host using interface *wlan0*:

```
# ip netns add testwifi
# ip link add link wlan0 name ipvl0 type ipvlan mode l2
# ip link set dev ipvl0 netns testwifi up
# ip -n testwifi address add 192.0.2.99/24 dev ipvl0
# ip -n testwifi route add default via 192.0.2.1
# ip netns exec testwifi ping -q -c1 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 5.372/5.372/5.372/0.000 ms
```

---

I seriously doubt that NetworkManager has any option related to 4 addresses mode. As for *IPVLAN/IPVTAP* this has to be supported by the container/virtualization application, like [LXC](https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/lxc-3-2-1-has-been-released/5322) or libvirt (which doesn't appears to support IPVTAP natively), not really by NetworkManager.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't give you positive feedback because my reputation is too low but this is a good explanation of what I thought to be true, but didn't have the technical knowledge of in entirety. I found the mac 80211 hwsim kernel module and intend to try that but if what you're saying is true then I will need hostapd and my interfaces will most likely not support DHCP, which is disheartening. Thanks for the explanation kind stranger!

Comment: I didn't mention one thing: some interfaces can support multiple connections at once. Usually they have to use the same freq and give one STA + one AP. But some can support multiple STA (probably ath9k based). That wouldn't be bridging (the bridge would be done on the AP in the end), but it could help. Check for example there: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328212/single-wifi-card-connect-to-multiple-access-points-simultaneously (this is STA+AP in the answer) . This one is about connecting twice: https://askubuntu.com/questions/488588/how-do-i-connect-to-multiple-wifi-networks .

Comment: How does 802.11s tie into this? I gather it's not wds.

Comment: @sinabala no idea, didn't hear about "s" before. Reading Wikipedia, I note that b.a.t.m.a.n which is a layer built over any "normal" Wifi appears to have a similar goal (mesh).

Comment: @A.B nevertheless, thanks! I *think* Batman is more of a tunneling approach, but I'm not sure.