# Qemu virt-manager setup bridge from wireless interface

Tags: networking, network-interface, kvm, bridge

I want to make my virtual machines visible in LAN using the 192.168.1.0/24 ip addresses as if they are a separate device in my LAN. Every tutorial I find has instructions about how to do it via ethernet wired connection, but I want this to happen using WiFi wireless connection. I want to achieve the bridged connection Virtual Box makes with qemu/kvm virt-manager.

The closest thing I found is in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/854257) where it says that wireless is possible but not the same way as wired. So what is that other way? Any help please?

Comment: The possible way with wireless is using NATed networking I stead of a bridge.

Comment: But by using NAT will my VMs be visible in my LAN? I want to set up a firewall in my VM. Is a NATed network what I'm looking for?

Comment: Not really, no. But that's a limitation of wifi, it doesn't support promiscuous mode required for a bridge. You might make do with openvswitch, but I haven't tried it personally

Comment: See this related Q/A where I made an answer that explains a STAtion client wireless interface set as STAtion client (rather than Access Point) can't be bridged, most of the time: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/554331/theoretical-tap-interface-w-wifi-parent-interface

Comment: I am also trying to bridge virt-manager with WiFi adapter, and have found it should be possible. Debian wiki mentions ebtables: https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections#Bridging_with_a_wireless_NIC However, I am also reading ebtables has been superseded by nftables: https://netfilter.org/projects/nftables/index.html: Quote: "**nftables** replaces the popular **{ip,ip6,arp,eb}tables**." The wiki page also got a script for manually configuring each ebtables rules when bridging with WiFi, so I suspect it should be a way to script this this each guest OS that should use a WiFi bridge. If s