# A solution to bridge wlan0 or permit to use the same lan for tap/br?

Tags: wifi, bridge, wlan, tap

I have a tftp server on lan 192.168.0.0/24
I want a qemu vm reach it, with ethernet is simple

a) First create br0

```
MAC1="52:54:$(dd if=/dev/urandom count=1 2>/dev/null | md5sum | sed 's/^\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\).*$/\1:\2:\3:\4/')";
nmcli con add ifname br0 type bridge con-name br0 bridge.mac-address $MAC1
```

b) then add eth0 as slave, then you can add vnet* or tap* interfaces with qemu or libvirt

With wlan is impossible

```
brctl addif br0 wlan1
can't add wlan1 to bridge br0: Operation not supported
```

nmcli fail also with timeout

So I have two solutions, create a "virbr" with libvirt and the use iptables rules
for natting it, but the virbr must have a different lan address (192.168.1.0/24 or 10.2.1.0/24 or whatever you want but not an address of ip range used by wlan because exit with errors) or create an empty br0 with network-manager and then assign a ip address to it and with iptables route to wlan0

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i br0 -o wlan1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan1 -o br0 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan1 -j MASQUERADE
```

but when I try to get a dhcp address from 192.168.0.0/24 lan it fail.
Any advice to use 192.168.0.0/24 ip for wlan "bridge"? Thanks

Edit: the iw command to "enable" the wlan0 as slave fail

```
iw dev wlan1 set 4addr on
command failed: Operation not supported (-95)
```

Comment: This Q/A explains that the limitation is inherent to the de facto deployment of Wifi on your own Access Point: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/554331/theoretical-tap-interface-w-wifi-parent-interface . It's not an OS limitation. But in addition you might also have a hardware/firmware/driver limitation on the NIC. Both sides require support (your side and more importantly because more rare: the AP).

Comment: Note: on my ath9k NIC, your command works: it depends on the NIC. On Intel NIC works too. Fails on a mediatek NIC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Waiting for better solution
I consider ok this solution atm: the wifi cannot be "bridged" for a driver issue or limit.