# How to configure bridged networking for KVM virtual machines in Kali Linux host?

Tags: networking, network-interface, networkmanager, kvm, bridge

My base/host machine is running Kali Linux. It is a fresh install. My purpose is to configure the use of Bridged network mode in the KVM virtual machines I install and run on top of this host OS. I tried to follow this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KFVe0-B2yLI). Following are the details.

During installation of host OS, I got the following question and I selected **`wlan0`** . Also, during the installation, I was asked for the password of **WiFi**, and it got connected to Wifi. The WiFi device gets internet from outside via an ethernet cable connected into it.

[image]

After installation of the OS, the network situation is like this:

[image]

Then I went ahead and followed the entire YouTube tutorial linked above. Initially, *i.e. before editing `/etc/network/interfaces`, my `/etc/network/interfaces` file, and my network interfaces situation looked like below:

[image]

[image]

I followed the tutorial and edited the `/etc/network/interfaces` file, after which it looked like as follows. **Notice how the state of br0 is `unknown`. Shouldn't it be `up`?**

[image]

[image]

**After `sudo systemctl restart networking`, my internet stopped working. I could not even ping gateway (192.168.10.1) and kept getting `Destination Host Unreachable`. My question is why and what do I do to fix it?**

Comment: It seems that you are trying to use Kali (from `https://www.kali.org`: __Kali Linux__ is an open-source, Debian-based Linusecurityx distribution geared towards various information tasks, such as Penetration Testing, Security Research, Computer Forensics and Reverse Engineering. ) as a general purpose Linux system. This is unwise. Rather, install a supported Ubuntu release. You can build or install any of the tools.

Comment: @waltinator In this case, I see nothing that would _prevent_ the user from doing what they want with the Linux distribution they picked.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thank you so much for saying that. I take the advice in general, but in this particular case, what difference does the distro make? Kali is debian based.

Comment: @Shy Kali _is_ for penetration testing etc. and is not _supposed_ to be used as a generic Linux system (see e.g. https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/).  However, seeing as you have already picked the system on top of which you plan to do stuff, rather than persuade you to change your choice, we should be able to help you.  This may result in you switching to a more suitable system, or in actually getting stuff going on Kali.

Comment: @Kusalananda It is working with Ethernet. See! It has nothing to do with Kali. Moreover, I just can't understand why a penetration tester can't do a simple thing such as getting VMs run in bridged mode. If I do change my system, to Ubuntu for example, I'll come back here and give you proof that the problem persists in Ubuntu as well. It has to do with Bridged and WiFi and KVM etc.

Comment: Your question: 1/ includes pictures of text making it a low quality question. When it's text, use text.  2/ was cross-posted (but closed) there: https://serverfault.com/questions/1147353/how-to-configure-bridged-networking-for-kvm-virtual-machines-in-kali-linux-host don't do cross-posts. Actually it's a closure reason in itself here on UL SE. 3/ now about Wifi: this Q/A tells why it's not possible 99% of the time to bridge Wifi (are you in the remaining 1% ?): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/554331/theoretical-tap-interface-w-wifi-parent-interface .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is not Kali. While I in general agree that Kali is not a good choice if you don't need Kali, it should support bridging.

But bridging [with wifi](https://oldwiki.archive.openwrt.org/doc/howto/clientmode?s%5B%5D=bridging#bridged_client_mode_issues) is difficult.

In this case I would suggest the following possibilities:

1. Use Ethernet, and bridge that. I don't see any mistakes in the configuration here, so I believe this should work.
2. Use NAT or L3 forwarding with WiFi.
3. Use a product such as VMWare that's able to emulate bridging over WiFi, by using some arcane black magic.